# Overflowing text in Hot Meta Posts box

Tags: bug, status-deferred, design, per-site-meta, community-bulletin

I've noticed the text of the Hot Meta Posts box is not within its limits. I guess this would happen for any question with a word that's long enough:

[image: image with text overflowing from Hot Meta Posts limits]

Comment: [also reported at MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387533/839601)